# How to Convert an angular whole project as Angular library is it possible

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-library, angular13

I have built a project in Angular 13. I need to convert the whole project into an angular library. Using that Angular Library I need to use it in another angular project.[image: My project basic structure mentioned below]

---

Comment: Create lib project and copy paste - either code or *.json config files

Answer (score 2):

You need to start a new Angular **library** project. Take the code that you want to modularize and paste it in this project.

Build, compile, test and finally publish said project as a library through **npmjs**, and you should be able to just import it into other projects through `npm install`.

Comment: Can you give any reference or example, please

Comment: @Sreejith try the [official guide from Angular](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries)